# How to create secret in existing keyvault with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I have a simple Terraform config to create secret in Azure keyvault.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "SomeApp-DEV" {
  name = "SomeApp-DEV"
  resource_group_name = "SomeApp"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test-secret" {
  name = "some-key"
  value = "test value"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.SomeApp-DEV
}
```

After `terraform plan` I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on secret.tf line 13, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test-secret":
  13:   key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.SomeApp-DEV
    ├────────────────
    │ data.azurerm_key_vault.SomeApp-DEV is object with 17 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "key_vault_id": string required.
```

How to make it work? I don't know what this `object with 17 attributes` message even means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you access the exported attribute with the namespace `data.<type>.<name>`, then you are accessing the entire Map of exported attributes from that data (this is also true of exported attributes for resources). In this situation, you only want the String for the `id`, whose value is assigned to the key `id` in the Map of exported attributes:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test-secret" {
  name = "some-key"
  value = "test value"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.SomeApp-DEV.id
}
```

and this will fix your issue.